# Can you control another program .exe? I have tried using send keys but this is unreliable

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

```
Private Const sw_restore = 9
```

`#If VBA7 Then`

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function showwindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal ncmdshow As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function isiconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function showwindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal ncmdshow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function isiconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub openProgram()

Dim strDirectory As String
Dim pID As Variant, sh As Variant
strDirectory = "H:\LocalStorage\Program.exe"
Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")
For Each w In sh.Windows
If w.document.folder.self.Path = strDirectory Then
If CBool(isiconic(w.hwnd)) Then
w.Visible = False
w.Visible = True
End If
Exit Sub
End If
Next
pID = Shell("H:\LocalStorage\Program.exe", vbNormalFocus)

waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{Right}", True
waittime 3000
Application.SendKeys "{%}", True

End Sub

Function waittime(ByVal milliseconds As Double)
Application.Wait (Now() + milliseconds / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

I need the key either {%} or {END} to register with the program to tab up to the next row of options. To then go right twice then press enter on Reports. Then down a couple of times to Create new report. Then keep using the sketchy and unreliable sendkeys until I can automate every report I need to run every week. Save some time. I would prefer to use something more robust than sendkeys. Are there other viable options? Thanks

Comment: You are right, `SendKeys` is unreliable. If the program has an exposed object model, then you can control is using VBA or any other object oriented programming language. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: There are desktop automation tools available which may be more robust than sendkeys.  They may not be free, but neither is your time (or sanity).

Comment: Is there any particular issue you face with SendKeys? Any combo, or spot where it is failing you? A lot of the unreliability may come from the fact that you have focus being lost. Also best to factor out the keystroke, and also wait for specific elements to appear if need be...

Comment: This is what AutoIT was made for: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/